# Suddenly getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException no bean named" with correct configs

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, javabeans

I have a desktop app in Java that connects to a MySql database through Hibernate.

I have the following files for configuration:

- pom.xml, where I put some stuff and database profiles
- [app_name]_context.xml, where I put the main configuration, including the beans and the datasource
- [app_name]_hibernate.cfg.xml, where I put the mappings to the tables

The app is almost finished, everything was working 100%, but then I decided to change the configuration to create DB profiles (before that the pom.xml didn't include any profile).
So I created the profiles in pom.xml and referenced them from context.xml. Everything was working. Then I wanted the SQL to be printed to the terminal for debugging, and for some reason, it wasn't being printed. So I changed the database configurations until I got it right. Everything was working. Then I changed it to the way it was before the sql-print changes, the exact configuration it was working before, but now I'm getting this error for a bean that was always there, and was never changed.

Here's some code to understand it better:

The datasource in context.xml: (the ${} strings are filtered and replaced with the real values stored in pom.xml)

```
<bean id="desenvolvimentoDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${db.mysql.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${db.mysql.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${db.mysql.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The current profile being used, in pom.xml:

```
<profile>
        <id>HOMOLOGACAO</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <profile.group>HOMOLOGACAO</profile.group>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            <db.show_sql>true</db.show_sql>
            <db.format_sql>false</db.format_sql>
            <db.mysql.url>[filtered]</db.mysql.url>
            <db.mysql.username>[filtered]</db.mysql.username>
            <db.mysql.password>[filtered]</db.mysql.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

The resource part of pom.xml, that tells Spring to filter those context.xml strings to the profiles values:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/configuracao</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And finally, the bean that is giving me the error:

```
<bean name="servidorUDP"
    class="br.uff.pgci.sgca.gateway.server.ServidorUDP"
    scope="singleton"/>
```

Resuming, I created the database profiles to organize the configurations, changed some database configurations back and forth, and suddenly I'm getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException no bean named ServidorUDP" error.

Could this be caused by misplaced linebreaks, or spaces, or wrong open/close xml tags? I'm pretty sure this isn't the case, but we never know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where exactly you placed your [app_name]_context.xml? Does the filters you introduced in the pom is skipping the bean definition xml?

Check this maven pom reference http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html, it might give you some clues.

Comment: Oh, the resource directory was wrong, my manager told me to put "src/main/resources/configuracao" instead of just "src/main/resources", probably that's what broke it. It's funny because he's the one who knows Spring, Hibernate and all that stuff, I pretty much just copy and paste hibernate stuff so far. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Good that you fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the context file containing servidorUDP is not found, possibly because your changes to profiles have stopped the file being copied to the correct place on the classpath. Review the contents of target/classes directory to ensure that the file is where you expect it be and review the logs to see evidence that it has been loaded. Spring logs a list of all beans found at some point, look for that and verify which beans are missing.

Comment: There's only one context file, the one that contains the database info and all the beans that I'm using. The only real change I made to the configuration structure was to move the db config from the hibernate.cfg.xml file to the pom, and let the context reference the pom to get the values.